# How to efficiently merge 2 dataframes on multiple columns and on multiple conditions

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf

I have 2 R dataframes, each with more than a million rows, of genomic coordinates and need to find out which one overlap (by any amount). Therefore, I need to know the rows where df1.chr = df2.chr and where df1.start (or df1.end) is in between df2.start and df2.end or where df2.start (or df2.end) is in between df1.start and df1.end. If this can make the algorithm easier, I really only need to how many overlap, not necessarily which one.

Example dataframe 1

```
df1 <- data.frame("chr" = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr3"), 
                  "start" = c(32826450, 49416884, 49417450, 49417523, 144385631), 
                  "end" = c(32826456, 49416890, 49417456, 49417529, 144385637))
```

Example dataframe 2

```
df2 <- data.frame("chr" = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2"), 
                  "start" = c(32826455, 45259551, 49417440), 
                  "end" = c(32826458, 45259557, 49417453))
```

Using sqldf I could easily obtain the answer with

```
sqldf("SELECT *
      FROM df1
      JOIN df2
      ON
      df1.chr = df2.chr and
      ((df1.start BETWEEN df2.start and df2.end or
        df1.end BETWEEN df2.start and df2.end) or
       (df2.start BETWEEN df1.start and df1.end or
        df2.end BETWEEN df1.start and df1.end))")
```

to get

```
   chr    start      end chr..4 start..5   end..6
1 chr1 32826450 32826456   chr1 32826455 32826458
2 chr2 49417450 49417456   chr2 49417440 49417453
```

But this take hours to complete.

Is there a more efficient way to proceed? I tried looking at both dplyr and data.table but could never get all parts to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You only need the df1.start between ... or df2.start between ... conditions since if neither start is within the other's range they must be disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be much easier to use the bioconductor library [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) for this task.

```
df1 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df1)
df2 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df2)

> sum(countOverlaps(df1, df2))
[1] 2
```

[HelloRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/HelloRanges/inst/doc/tutorial.pdf) is a great resource on how to perform common tasks on GRanges.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
cols <- c("chr","i.start","i.end","x.start","x.end")
unique(rbindlist(list(
    df2[df1, on=.(chr, start<=start, end>=start), nomatch=0L, mget(cols)],
    df2[df1, on=.(chr, start<=end, end>=end), nomatch=0L, mget(cols)],
    df2[df1, on=.(chr, start<=start, end>=start), nomatch=0L, mget(cols)],
    df2[df1, on=.(chr, start<=end, end>=end), nomatch=0L, mget(cols)]
)))
```

output:

```
    chr  i.start    i.end  x.start    x.end
1: chr2 49417450 49417456 49417440 49417453
2: chr1 32826450 32826456 32826455 32826458
```